# What happens internally when a javascript function is called?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand in depth what happens when i call a javascript function.

My first goal is to log something like `voila` whenever `any` function is called. When i say any means any. Let it be creation of instance from prototype. Or let it be a simple function call. Well i don't also care about the mess that i will get on screen.

Something like this

```
const oldCall = Function.prototype.call;
Function.prototype.call = function(cont, ...args) {
  console.log('voila');
  oldCall(cont, ...args);
}
```

Well we all know above will get stuck in infinite recursion because `oldCall` is again a function call.

But that is just to present my intention.

So what should be the perfect way?

In the worst case, I am even ok to create a new custom build for nodejs via patching v8.

Comment: I don't like what you're doing here. Don't do this. Move to another language and design your program such that it's built into it.

Answer (score 0):

> Well we all know above will get stuck in infinite recursion because oldCall is again a function call

It won't get stuck in a loop. Calling a function and calling the `.call` property of a function are entirely different things. While you can rewrite the `.call` property, you definetly cannot intercept a function call.

---

To properly understand what  `.call` is doing, have a look at this small polyfill:

```
Function.prototype.call = function(context, ...args) { // the .call property
  const fn = Symbol();
  context[fn] = this;
  context[fn](...args); // the real call
};
```

> So what should be the perfect way?

There is no way.

> In the worst case, I am even ok to create a new custom build for nodejs via patching v8.

Yup, sounds good, have fun :)

Comment: You are requested to copy and paste on console and let use know the outcomes.